# Pointers and linked list in C | Crash on display

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, crash

On running display() , program crashes.May be there is a problem in create().
I tried but i cant identify the problem.I am destroying their links but where? i dont know.It is a singly linked list.

node structure is

```
typedef struct node{
   int data;
   struct node *right;
}list;
```

Here is create()

```
void create(list *start){
int data;
    printf("Input value : ");
    scanf("%d",&data);
    if(data==0){
        start=NULL;
        return;
    }
    else{
        start=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
        start->data=data;
        create(start->right);
    }
}
```

And display() is

```
void display(list *start){
    printf("%d",start->data);
    if(start->right==NULL)return;
    display(start->right);
}
```

Comment: The address assigned to `start` does not get returned to the caller. You need to use double indrection (`list **start`) or return `start` as the function result. Note: if you had used a debugger to investigate this then the problem should have been immediately apparent.

Comment: What error you get from compiler? Would you paste that info? Perhaps make void display as int display()?

Comment: Compiler errors are 0 and 0 warning.using gcc

Comment: How do you call the `create()` and `display()` function. Post the complete code

Comment: Full Code temporarily posted @ http://uman.ga/tmp

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d",&data);
    if(data==0){
        start=NULL;
        return;
    }`  The posted error handling is nonsense.  a 0 is a valid input.  This is what should have been done: `If( scanf("%d",&data) != 1 ) { //handle error }  // implied else, scanf successful...

Comment: regarding: `void display(list *start)` and `start=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));`  1) the return type from any of the heap allocation functions is: `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) to change where a pointer points, the address of the pointer must be passed 4) the signature should be `void create(list **start)`  then dereference the 'start' via a single `*` to access the pointer location

Comment: regarding: `start=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
        start->data=data; create(start->right);`  this should be: `*start=malloc(sizeof(list));  if( !*start ) { perror( "malloc failed: ); } else {  (* start)->data=data; create(&(start->right));`

Comment: Nothing in the question text states that the user entering a 0 stops the recursive function: `create()`  so I have to assume that the checking for a 0 is a logic error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in `create()` function `start` should be of `list**` type if you want changes should affect in calling function `main()` function otherwise it's simply call by value.

```
void create(list **start) {
  /*some code */
}
```

Secondly, your recursive logic of linking node is correct as every time `start` points to new memory location & every time old memory is lost so there is  no link between the nodes.

So take extra `temp` pointer variable of `list` type. `create()` function looks like

```
void create(list **start,list *new){
        int data;
        printf("Input value : ");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        if(data != 0){
                new = malloc(sizeof(list));/*allocate memory */
                new->data = data;/*put the data */
                new->right  = *start; /*new node right should be head ptr */
                *(start) = new; /*update the head ptr */
                create(start,new);
        }
        else
                return;
}
```

And from `main()` call the `create()` like this

```
int main(void) {
        list *head_ptr = NULL, *temp = NULL;
        create(&head_ptr,temp);
        display(head_ptr);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: so many errors in this answer, I don't know where to (sic) start

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `create()` allocates new nodes but loses the pointers to them, this is a perfect example of memory leak.

This happens, because when you pass pointer to function, you pass it's value and the local parameter is just something on the stack that has this value - the local parameter is not the same pointer as the pointer you passed to the function, it only has the same value.

So when you allocate new node, you make the local pointer point to the new node, not the pointer you passed to the function and when the function exits this local pointer does not exist anymore and you lose the reference to the located memory - memory leak happens.

So how do you change the pointer you passed to the function from inside the function?It's simple - just pass to the function the address of the pointer.
When you want to change some variable, you make a pointer point to it's address and then you dereference the pointer.Here you will do the same - take the address of the pointer and dereference a double pointer that points to it.
Just minor changes are needed like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *right;
}list;

void create(list **start){
    int data;
        printf("Input value : ");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        if(data==0){
            start=NULL;
            return;
        }
        else{
            *start=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
            (*start)->data=data;
            create(&(*start)->right);
        }
}

void display(list *start){
    printf("%d",start->data);
    if(start->right==NULL)return;
    display(start->right);
}


int main(void){
    list *LIST=NULL;

    create(&LIST);
    display(LIST);
    return 0;
}
```